# How do Lego train carriages couple together no matter how you place them?

Tags: electromagnetism

I bought a Lego train (Lego item #60197) for my daughter's birthday and we have just assembled it.

There's a magnetic mechanism for carriage coupling (I say magnetic as it feels like a magnet).

I coupled two carriages together and thought: *Hey, I must have been lucky placing this two together* (as in placing N magnetic pole next to S pole, so they attract). *I'm pretty sure, that when I rotate the carriage it will start to repel.* But to my surprise it attracted as well.

So I've checked every pair of 5 couplers in the box and all of them attracted to one another.

How does one construct such device?

Edit: pictures, as requested:
[image: Lego piece]
[image]

Edit 2: I've tried turning one part of coupling upside down. It still attracts.

Then I've tried rotating one element against another (to upside down and back, covering the whole 360°), but still no repel. I thought that maybe I felt reduced attraction at some angle, but it probably was false positive, as it's hard for me to replicate this for specific angle. I may have to build something more complicated to measure change in attraction force.

Comment: Believe it or not there is an SE site for Lego issues : [bricks.se].

Comment: I'm aware of that. I just think of it as more physics question of having a magnetic device with force always attracting than Lego question.

Comment: Can you post pictures of the connection?

Comment: You could take the easy way out and break open one of the carriages but I don't think your daughter would be to happy with that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the magnet on an axis perpendicular to the carriage, e.g. N to the left at the front of the carriage, S to the right. At the back of the carriage, the axis faces the other way, S to the left, N to the right. Turn the carriage around, so that front becomes back, and you also turn the magnets, so that the positions of N and S are preserved. To check, try turning a carriage upside down.

One way they could do it so that it always attracts, even with the carriage upside down, is if the magnets are free to rotate about a central axis (aligned with the carriage). Then they would align themselves. This might also be cheaper to manufacture as they would not have to check the alignment during assembly.

Also, they could have the magnets free to rotate about an axis perpendicular to the carriage. I think you will have to break one to be sure.

Comment: Oh my god! I feel so stupid now!

Comment: Hold the press: I've just turned it upside down. It still attracts.

Comment: Probably to get it to repel you need to get the alignment just so. It only has to shift a bit to  one side and it will attract. Depending on the length of the magnet used, this may be quite a small amount.

Comment: I think a quadrupole arrangement would allow for this: four magnets arranged in a 2x2 box with N-S on top and S-N on the bottom.

Comment: @CrazyYoghurt Can you try connecting the carriages after rotating one of them 90 degrees?

Comment: @MarkH I've done the whole 360°, no noticeable change

Comment: @CharlesFrancis your update makes perfect sense. Thank you very much! I'm so curious that I'm considering ordering one piece like that just to break it apart. I'll post an update if that will be the case :)